# Drupal: Nothing of CSS3 won´t work on IE? Specially Google webfonts. is this code correct?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, webfonts

I´m currently working on www.liganet.net, and it looks ok in Chrome and Firefox.
But look at it with ANY Internet Explorer version... the rounded corners go away, everything looks bad. Specially the Google Webfonts.
I´ve installed the Drupal module "Google Fonts" so I can use Google fonts easier.
But I think that the problem has nothing to do with Drupal.

This is the code that should show the page title with the webfonts format:

```
.logo-1 {font-family:delius; font-size:18pt; margin-top:-35px;}
.logo-2 {font-family:chewy; font-size:44pt; margin-top:-25px; color:#133793;}
.logo-3 {font-family:delius; font-size:19pt; margin-top:-26px; text-align:right;}
```

So those three linkes should define the way that the title shows up. IE won´t show the google font.

And here are some rounded borders, shadows and ribbons that won´t show up at all!

```
border: 1px solid #6487DC;
*border-top: 1px solid #6487DC;
*border-bottom: 1px solid #6487DC;
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /* FF1+ */
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /* Saf3+, Chrome */
border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9 */


-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
-o-box-shadow:2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
box-shadow:2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

I´ve [checked out](http://jigsaw.w3.org) that all that code should work in IE, maybe I´m forgetting something?
I would really appreciate some help or guidance about this.
THANKS!
Rosamunda

> UPDATE:

Thanks for your answer!
I´ve tried to understand the errors, specially the ones related to the webfonts.
The site that you´ve kindly told me http://jigsaw.w3.org, tells me that the code should say:

```
@font-face {
font-family : "'Abel'";
font-style : normal;
font-weight : normal;
src : local('Abel'), local('Abel-Regular'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/abel/v1/N59kklKPso9WzbZH9jwJSg.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

But after changing that in my .css file it won´t work.
Many of the errors are belonging to Drupal modules that work just fine, and the ones related to webfonts, should get fixed with those lines added to the file.

But it won´t work...

Comment: You've got quite a few css errors (not to mention a few HTML errs) that would be worth checking out and fixing.  
[41 CSS Errors - W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=+www.liganet.net&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trying and error, I´ve found (pretty much astonished) that the problem was the Google Fonts module itself.
Yes. I´ve uninstalled it, and went to http://www.google.com/webfonts, selected the fonts I wanted to use and did a quick copy/paste of the single line of code that Google gave me.
FYI, it was this line:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Delius|Chewy|Rokkitt:400,700|Coustard' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I put that inside the `<head>` of `page.tpl.php` and voilá!
Not only the fonts, but everything else is working (the other CSS3 stuff that did look horrible up until now :)

Anyway, I just wanted to post the solution, just in case anyone else bumps into this problem.